# Unable to extract .tar.xz files

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics, tar, gpu-driver

I am new to Linux and I am trying to install AMD drivers on my system. For this I downloaded the file from AMD website. It is called `amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504.tar.xz`. In the website it says that I have to extract the file using the following command

```
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.30-450654.tar.xz
```

But when I do this, I am getting the following error.

```
username@Lenovo:~/Downloads$ tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504.tar.xz
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I install extract it? What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Are you sure it was a .xz file? The error you're getting means xz doesn't think it's an xz file.

Comment: What happens with the command `tar -xvf amdgpu-pro-17.30-450654.tar.xz` (without the J)? Could the file be damaged or given the wrong extension?

Comment: Same error again

Comment: use `file amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504.tar.xz` to check what it is.

Comment: @Rinzwind Now gives the output saying : amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504.tar.xz: data

Comment: It the file fully downloaded yet?

Comment: @mikewhatever Yes it is

Comment: If file says it's just data, the download was probably corrupted. Download again

Answer (score 7):

xz-utils  can extract xz compressed files

Install it with the following command:

`sudo apt install xz-utils -y`

Then use it as below to extract your file:

`xz -d  amdgpu-pro-17.30-450654.tar.xz`

Comment: Worth noting that the command in this answer will automatically remove the .xz file unless you append -k option.

Answer (score 3):

```
tar -xvf amdgpu-pro-17.30-450654.tar.xz
```

No need for J in the beginning! With J you are filtering it, but usually it's not neccessary.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a bit?

Comment: When I remove the `J`, I get a new error... "tar: This does not look like a tar archive".